# Proving a series for $\pi$ by Plouffe

Tags: nt.number-theory, dirichlet-series

Simon Plouffe found experimentally a series for $\pi$ that can be written as

$$\frac{\pi}{24} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{3}{e^{\pi n}-1} -\frac{4}{e^{2\pi n}-1} +\frac{1}{e^{4\pi n}-1}\right) $$

A related series for $\log(2)$, easily found with lindep in PARI, is
$$\frac{\log(2)}{8} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{2}{e^{\pi n}-1} -\frac{3}{e^{2\pi n}-1} +\frac{1}{e^{4\pi n}-1}\right) $$

Linas Vepstas proves several formulas similar to these in his paper [On Plouffe's Ramanujan Identities](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609775.pdf), for constants of the form $\zeta(4m-1)$ , $\zeta(4m+1)$ and related powers of $\pi$.

However, regarding $\pi$ and $\log(2)$, the closest expression found in the reference is

$$S_1(2\pi)+T_1(2\pi) = \frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{3}{4}\log(2)$$

where
$$S_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{xn}-1)}$$
and
$$T_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{xn}+1)}$$

Therefore, there seems to be another similar equation that would allow for proving the above two series for $\pi$ and $\log(2)$, by eliminating for one constant or the other.

> What is this second equation involving $\pi$ and $\log(2)$ ?

Comment: What are $S_1$ and $T_1$?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: a proof of Plouffe's formula for $\pi$ is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938644/87355

Comment: Log(2) explicitly proved at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912428/how-can-we-show-that-ln2-sum-n-1-infty-1n-1-over-n-left12-ove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is immediate to show that
$S_1(x)=-x/24-\log(\eta(ix/(2\pi)))$
and $T_1(x)=S_1(x)-2S_1(2x)$, so all these formulas are immediate
consequences of the properties of the Dedekind $\eta$ function.

Answer (score 0):

$T_1(x)$ and $S_1(x)$ are related by $T_1(x)=S_1(x)-2S_1(2x)$

Therefore,

$$S_1(2\pi)+T_1(2\pi)=\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{3}{4}\log(2)$$

is equivalent to

$$2S_1(2\pi)-2S_1(4\pi) = \frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{3}{4}\log(2)$$

This equation accounts for the second and third term of the series. Now, since $S_1(\pi)$ is needed as well, the missing equation is found (experimentally) to be

$$S_1(\pi)+T_1(\pi)=\frac{\pi}{12}-\frac{\log(2)}{4}$$

A more complete answer would derive this expression from an equation similar to theorem 7 in Vepstas' article.